# Difference between QSharedPointer::isNull() and operator!()

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr, qsharedpointer

in Qt docs we read:

```
bool QSharedPointer::operator! () const

Returns true if this object is null. 
This function is suitable for use in if-constructs, like:

 if (!sharedptr) { ... }
```

and

```
bool QSharedPointer::isNull () const
Returns true if this object is holding a reference to a null pointer.
```

What is the difference between these two functions? This is clear what is reference to a null pointer, but what means here

> "if the object is null" ?

What determines if `QSharedPointer` ***is null***? How do these functions correspond to `QSharedPointer::data() != null` ?

Comment: I would say both are equivalent. If you check the source, it might even be that one of the functions call the other.

Comment: From Qt sources of `QSharedPointer` class: `inline bool operator !() const { return isNull(); }` - confirms what @JoachimPileborg said.

Comment: @vahancho you can put it as an answer, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Some coding standards frown upon verbosity, others enshrine it. Qt caters to both crowds, hence the two methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Qt sources of the `QSharedPointer` class:

```
inline bool operator !() const { return isNull(); }
```

This confirms what @JoachimPileborg said in his comment - `isNull()` function and `operator!()` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

A "null" QSharedPointer wraps a T* t where t equals 0/NULL/nullptr. That's what's meant with "object is null"

isNull() and operator!() are equivalent, you can use either one.

A shared pointer is null by default, or when set to 0/nullptr explicitly:

```
QSharedPointer<T> t; //null
QSharedPointer<T> t2(new T); //not null
QSharedPointer<T> t3(0); //null
QSharedPointer<T> t4(nullptr); //null
t2.clear(); //not null before, now null
```

Comment: @jdi: It has several reset() overloads in Qt 5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#reset But as clear() exists in both Qt 4 and Qt 5, this is indeed more generic.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at Qt4 compatibility. I should have checked Qt5 before editing!