# QSharedPointer does not return false

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qsharedpointer

I currently have something like this

```
QSharedPointer<QMainWindow> cv;
```

This shared pointer is used as

```
cV = QSharedPointer<QMainWindow>(new QMainWindow(p));
cV->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_DeleteOnClose);
cV->show();
```

Now if I close the the `QMainWindow` then the following code makes the app crash

```
if(cV)
    cV->close(); //This pointer is no longer valid.
```

My Question is when I closed the`cV`  `QMainWindow` Object (by clicking on the x button of the ) why is the following statement  returning true

```
if(cV)
```

How could i make it return `false` if the Window has been closed?

Comment: I am not sure if QScopedPointer would be suitable for this. QScopedPointer is deleted automatically after a scope ends. the cV pointer is a class member variable being used by different methods. I am not sure how Scoped Pointer would help me here ?

Comment: also if(cv) and (cv.isNull()) are the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925693/qt-difference-between-qsharedpointerisnull-and-operator

Answer (score 5):

A shared pointer doesn't magically know when you delete the object it points to. It is *an error* to manually delete an object whose lifetime is managed by a shared pointer. Since the window self-deletes when it gets closed, you now get dangling shared pointers.

Ergo, you can't use `QSharedPointer` with a widget that is `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`.

What you need is a pointer that tracks whether the widget still exists. Such pointer is `QPointer`, it does exactly what you need. That pointer is designed to reset itself to zero when a `QObject` gets destroyed.

Note that `QPointer` is a weak pointer, it won't delete the window when it goes out of scope.

If you need an owning pointer that allows deletion of the underlying `QObject`, there's a way to do it:

```
template <typename T> class ScopedQObjectPointer {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(ScopedQObjectPointer)
  QPointer<T> m_ptr;
  inline void check() const {
    Q_ASSERT(m_ptr && (m_ptr->thread() == 0
             || m_ptr->thread() == QThread::currentThread()));
  }
public:
  explicit ScopedQObjectPointer(T* obj = 0) : m_ptr(obj) {}
  ScopedQObjectPointer(ScopedQObjectPointer &&other) : m_ptr(other.take()) {}
  ~ScopedQObjectPointer() { check(); delete m_ptr; }
  operator T*() const { check(); return m_ptr; }
  T & operator*() const { check(); return *m_ptr; }
  T * operator->() const { check(); return m_ptr; }
  T * data() const { check(); return m_ptr; }
  T * take() { check(); T * p = m_ptr; m_ptr.clear(); return p; }
  void reset(T * other) { check(); delete m_ptr; m_ptr = other; }
  operator bool() const { check(); return m_ptr; }
};
```

Since we allow the deletion of the object through other means than the pointer, it is an error to access the object from multiple threads. If the object were to be deleted in another thread, there's a race condition between the null check and the use of dereferenced object. Thus, a `QPointer`, or a `ScopedObjectPointer` can only be used from object's thread. This is explicitly asserted. The `Q_ASSERT` becomes a no-op in release builds and has no performance impact there.

Comment: +1 for the template that acts like the not-working QScopedPointer<QPointer<object> >

Comment: Sorry, I mean QScopedPointer<QPointer<T> > !

Comment: @fxam A `QScopedPointer<QPointer<T>>` is a scoped pointer that manages an instance of a `QPointer`. Sure it will work, but it won't be useful for anything much: there's not much point in storing `QPointer<T>` on the heap.

Comment: we learn everyday. I have never used QPointer and feel suddenly stupid.

Comment: @UmNyobe Oh, I learn every day, too. Not feeling "stupid" almost all the time is an indication one doesn't learn enough!

Comment: The QPointer is only useful in certain circumstances: only for objects living in the same thread where you access the QPointer. I've amended the class to make it explicit that the use of a `QPointer` from other threads is always an error, since there's a race condition between the null check and use of the dereferenced instance.

Comment: @KubaOber I've been in situation where QPointer is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

The object guarded by QSharedPointer is meant to be deleted by QSharedPointer itself when all owners go out of scope. In your case, you are letting QMainWindow to delete cV when user closes it. QSharedPointer has no knowledge about that incident and will not set the pointer to 0 automatically.

Your solution is simple. Forget about QSharedPointer and just use QPointer. QPointer will automatically set a pointer to 0 when the object is deleted by yourself or by QObject. You can then use **if (cV)**.

```
class foo {  

public:
  ~foo() {      
    delete cV; // delete cV if cV is not 0.
  }

  void showMainWindow() {
    if ( ! cV) {
      cV = new QMainWindow();
      cV->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    }
    cV->show();
  }
  void closeMainWindow() {
    if (cV) { // cV is 0 if it is already deleted when user closes it
      cV->close();
    }
  }

private:
  QPointer<QMainWindow> cV;
};
```

If you want to avoid **delete** in destructor and automatically deletes cV when it goes out of scope, you can use KubarOber's [ScopedQObjectPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319339/982459) in another answer to this question:

```
class foo {  

public:
  ~foo() {      
  }

  void showMainWindow() {
    if ( ! cV) {
      cV.reset(new QMainWindow());
      cV->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    }
    cV->show();
  }
  void closeMainWindow() {
    if (cV) { // cV is 0 if it is already deleted when user closes it
      cV->close();
    }
  }

private:
  ScopedQObjectPointer<QMainWindow> cV;
};
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed that you use a parent when creating cV: **new QMainWindow(p)**. Well if p is not null then p will delete cV when p is deleted. So there's no need to delete cV in destructor even if you use QPointer.

Comment: "is usually meant to" **Not usually. ALWAYS**. It is an **error** to delete what's pointed to by `QSharedPointer` or `std::shared_ptr`. What you advocate is correct, except that it's bad advice not to use an RTTI wrapper for this. An explicit delete in a destructor means you're not using the right class for the job. A good answer would be to actually write such a class, especially that it's trivial.

Comment: @KubaOber, OK removed **usually** :). But if we were to avoid delete in dtor, how do we delete cV (which is a QPointer) if user didn't close it? Did you mean to move cV to a RAII class which has a **delete** in its dtor?

Comment: @KubaOber, ok I think your ScopedQObjectPointer answered my question to you above :)

Comment: RAII means that you make a *class* to manage the resource, and then use that class to manage it. A `delete` in destructor means that you've missed a RAII class somewhere. Explicit resource management belongs in classes that are *dedicated* to managing those resources. That's why we have owning smart pointers: they do just one thing, and do it well: they manage a chunk of memory and the class instance living there.